# Angular2 Guards and router

Tags: angular, router

I have a login system which gives access to a module if and only if we are logged in. If we are not, and our session has expired, then I do redirect to the login page, and save in the session storage the page where we were, so if the user try to log in again, he goes back to the page he was on.
However, I am having an issue in my guard :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _router: Router, private _authUtils: AuthUtils) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if(this._authUtils.isLogged()) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('previousPage', this._router.url)
        let link = ["/login", { previous: "true" }]
        this._router.navigate(link) 
        return false
    }
  }
}
```

The issue comes from the fact that this._router.url is not yet initialized and thus returns '/' every time. If I force it to be equal to one of my route path, then it works perfectly fine. Any idea how could I fix this issue ?

Cheers!

EDIT:

Here is what I have in my app-routing.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
                {
                    path: 'myApp',
                    loadChildren: 'app/myApp.module#MyAppModule', 
                    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
                },
                {
                    path: 'login',
                    component: LoginComponent,
                    data: {
                        name: 'login'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '**',
                    redirectTo: '/login',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                }
            ]
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Please add code in your app.module where you declare your AuthGuard.

Comment: What do you want to see there, I mean it just appears in my providers : as : AuthGuard

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`RouterStateSnapshot`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterStateSnapshot-interface.html) from [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) paramater to get current URL.

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nWUUOpD39eNYWw50qFUH?p=preview).

So, I think you could change your `AuthGuard` to:

```
import {
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    CanActivate
} from '@angular/router';

// other import ....

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _router: Router, private _authUtils: AuthUtils) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if(this._authUtils.isLogged()) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('previousPage', state.url)
        let link = ["/login", { previous: "true" }]
        this._router.navigate(link) 
        return false
    }
  }
}
```